# Calling the function "startActivity" in other class and file doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I want call the function startActivity in two ways:

**First (It works):**

```
        public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == 1){
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:660718109")));
            }
            else {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;
}
```

**Second:**
in HelloActivity.java

```
    public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == 1){
            IntentsUtils.tryOneOfThese(this);
        }
        else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
}
```

in IntentsUtils.java

```
public class IntentsUtils
{
   public static void tryOneOfThese(Activity activity)
   {
       IntentsUtils.call(activity);
   }
   public static void call(Activity activity)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5555555555"));
      Log.v("MyLogs", "It's works!");
      activity.startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

The second way doesn't work - I have a error in aplication when I clicked on position in menu. I know function "call" in IntentsUtils work because analise logs in "LogCat"

This is my logs from LogCat:
android.permission.CALL_PHONE

android.permission.CALL_PHONE> 10-27 16:10:56.702:

> WARN/ActivityManager(52): Permission
>   Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.CALL
>   dat=tel:5555555555 flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster
>   } from ProcessRecord{43dbf4b8
>   363:com.androidbook/10025} (pid=363,
>   uid=10025) requires
>   android.permission.CALL_PHONE
>
> 10-27 16:10:56.722:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(363): threadid=3: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4001b188)
>
> 10-27 16:10:56.722:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(363): Uncaught
>   handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception
>
> 10-27 16:10:56.752:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(363):
>   java.lang.SecurityException:
>   Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.CALL
>   dat=tel:5555555555 flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster
>   } from ProcessRecord{43dbf4b8
>   363:com.androidbook/10025} (pid=363,
>   uid=10025) requires
>   android.permission.CALL_PHONEandroid.permission.CALL_PHONE

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting in LogCat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your action.

[ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) is restricted to specific apps (I think system apps only). The reason you get your logcat message is because you log it before you try to start the activity. A permission error is going to occur because the system will not allow your app to directly call a phone number. You can dial it, but the user has to press call.

This is a security issue, if they let any application start making phone calls to numbers.

From the Android SDK Documetation:

> Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL).

**edit**
after looking at your last edit, with the logcat. I can say 100% that your issue is with using ACTION_CALL.

Long story short, you do not have permission to use ACTION_CALL, you have to use ACTION_DIAL.

Comment: When I replace function ACTION_CALL to ACTION_DIAL aplication works. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as given in

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

you may have to set like this:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I havent tried this. But worth to give a try

Comment: I add this but it didn't help :(